# how do I start Webrick server on windows 10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

I am very new to Ruby on Rails. As I was setting up...everthing seem to be going fine until I ran "rails s".Webrik didnt start!

my OS is Windows 10.

I am using this tutorial http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/windows

Comment: Please show the log in console

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5rnz62dkb1p7m98/AABwc_o_gw7OjYRmZvnRdGUia?dl=0 LongNguyen

Comment: Please show the log errors

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b5zng5zvc2y99y2/Screenshot%20%2840%29.png?dl=0 @Prashant4224

Comment: Please go through this [Document](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) step by step

Comment: IT WORKS!! thanks soo much @Prashant4224

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you need to create new app `rails new my_app` then switch folder to /my_app and then you can do `rails s`

you have to read your logs